# Reset Index Count in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple rows per index and want to reset the count of the index but keeping the same multiple rows per index.

Example:

```
     | Name |
1234 |  AA  |
1234 |  AB  |
1235 |  BA  |
1235 |  BB  |
1236 |  CA  |
1236 |  CB  |
1237 |  DA  |
```

I'm trying to have something such as:

```
  |  Name   |
1 |   AA    |
1 |   AB    |
2 |   BA    |
2 |   BB    |
3 |   CA    |
3 |   CB    |
4 |   DA    |
```

Comment: ``df.index = df.index.factorize()[0] + 1``

Comment: `df.index = df.index.astype('category').codes + 1` as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `factorize`:

```py
df.index = df.index.factorize()[0] + 1
```

You could also use @Chris' solution in the comments.